# Python set intersection and __eq__

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

According to [this page](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576932-sets-with-a-custom-equalityuniqueness-function/), set.intersection test for element equality using the `__eq__` method. Can anyone then explain to me why this fails?

```
>>> Class Foo(object):
>>>     def __eq__(self, other):
>>>         return True
>>>
>>> set([Foo()]).intersection([Foo()])
set([])
```

Using 2.7.3. Is there another (not overly complex) way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you overwrite `__eq__` you should always overwrite `__hash__`, too.

> "If a == b, then it must be the case that hash(a) == hash(b), else sets
>   and dictionaries will fail." Eric

`__hash__` is used to generate an integer out of an object.
This is used to put the keys of a dict or the elements of sets into buckets so that one can faster find them.

If you do not overwrite `__hash__`, the default algorithm creates different hash-integers although the objects are equal.

In your case I would do this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return type(self) == type(other)
    def __hash__(self):
        return 1
```

Because all objects of your class are equal to every other object of that class they must all be in the same bucket(1) in the set. This way `in` returns also `True`.

What should `__eq__` be like:

- if you only compare Foo objects

  ```
  def __eq__(self, other):
      return self.number == other.number
  ```
- if you also compare Foo objects to other objects:

  ```
  def __eq__(self, other):
      return type(self) == type(other) and self.number == other.number
  ```
- if you have different classes with different algorithms for equal, I recommend [double-dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).

  ```
  class Foo:
      def __eq__(self, other):
          return hasattr(other, '_equals_foo') and other._equals_foo(self)
      def _equals_foo(self, other):
          return self.number == other.number
      def _equals_bar(self, other):
          return False # Foo never equals Bar
  class Bar:
      def __eq__(self, other):
          return hasattr(other, '_equals_bar') and other._equals_bar(self)
      def _equals_foo(self, other):
          return False # Foo never equals Bar
      def _equals_bar(self, other):
          return True # Bar always equals Bar
  ```

  This way both `a` and `b` in `a == b` decide what equal means.

Comment: Why is the `__eq__` needed? And if i inherit object, why do I need to override `__hash__` with a function that just calls objects `__hash__` method?

Comment: The question's code is simplified. I have a number I want to use as a hash (def __hash__(self): return self.number), and what I did in eq what to compare the two objects hashes. Is this correct? Or should I compare their types like in your code?

Comment: I think comparing the numbers only is ok. It will break when you have objects of different types in the set.

Comment: To clarify, if `a == b`, then it must be the case that `hash(a) == hash(b)`, else sets and dictionaries will fail.

Comment: Why is double dispatch useful here?

Comment: Thanks Eric, I cited you and added a useful exampe of double dispatch.